# Problem with Gradle build when trying to run vertx application

Tags: java, gradle, vert.x

´´´

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'io.vertx.vertx-plugin' version '1.2.0'
    
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web-client:4.0.2'
    
    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    
    
   
}
vertx {
  mainVerticle = 'Reactx.BackendVerticle'
}


//Backend Verticle.java
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package Reactx;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

public class BackendVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

     @Override
      public void start() {
        // Create an HTTP server which simply returns "Hello World!" to each request.
        // If a configuration is set it get the specified name
         Router router = Router.router(vertx);
            Route messageRoute = router.get("/api/message"); // (1)
            messageRoute.handler(rc -> {
              rc.response().end("Hello React from Vert.x!"); // (2)
            });

            router.get().handler(StaticHandler.create()); // (3)

            vertx.createHttpServer()
              .requestHandler(router)
              .listen(8080);
      }

  // tag::main[]
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(); // <1>
    vertx.deployVerticle(new BackendVerticle()); // <2>
  }
  // end::main[]
}
```

´´´
When I try to do gradle run, I am getting an error::compileJava Task failed.
How can this be solved? I cannot try kotlin because I have some dependency and I want to execute this only in gradle.build. I am using gradle version 6.6 which is also due to the dependency of project.
Adding failure stacktrace:

```
Gradle Version: 6.6
Java Home: C:\...\jdk1.8.0_282
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: run


> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:8: error: package io.vertx.ext.web does not exist
import io.vertx.ext.web.Route;
                       ^
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:9: error: package io.vertx.ext.web does not exist
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
                       ^
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:10: error: package io.vertx.ext.web.handler does not exist
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
                               ^
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
         Router router = Router.router(vertx);
         ^
  symbol:   class Router
  location: class BackendVerticle
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
         Router router = Router.router(vertx);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable Router
  location: class BackendVerticle
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            Route messageRoute = router.get("/api/message"); // (1)
            ^
  symbol:   class Route
  location: class BackendVerticle
C:\CMWorkspaceUpdated\Reactx\src\main\java\Reactx\BackendVerticle.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            router.get().handler(StaticHandler.create()); // (3)
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable StaticHandler
  location: class BackendVerticle
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 253ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: Can you provide any more detail about the failure?

Comment: @homerman added the failure stacktrace.Have a look!

Comment: you should add `compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:4.0.2'`dependency

Comment: @injecteer If you see my code above, I already added the dependency

Comment: you would get rid of compile error if you did. you added olny `vertx-web-client`

Comment: @injecteer Oh yes. I added and now I dont see build errors!Super.

Comment: @injecteer can you post that as solution so I could accept it?

Comment: @injecteer Also, which jar do I need to add for the package io.vertx.ext.web.Route?

Comment: not sure why you need a jar for, but here you go https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/vertx/vertx-web/4.0.2/vertx-web-4.0.2.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `vertx-web` as a dependency.

To fix the compilation issues you need to add:

```
dependencies {
    //...  
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:4.0.2'
}
```